# Trying to put JSON request in HTTPGet on android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

The api my app is working with is expecting a GET request for search results that looks like this:

```
Method: GET
Headers:
{
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-AUTHORIZATION": "8eb40dba2f0c6d7de8b9c6e1865aa507"
}
Request:
{
    "keyword": "X S"
}
Response:
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 0,
    "meta": {
        "exec_time": 0.012183904647827
    },
    "message": "",
    "data": [

    ]
}
```

I have a class called `HttpGetWithEntity` that i found online that looks like this:

```
public class HttpGetWithEntity extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public HttpGetWithEntity() {
        super();
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }

    public HttpGetWithEntity(String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return HttpGet.METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

and i am implementing it like so:

```
public HttpResponse invokeXAUTHGETJsonService(String url, String token,
            String jsonPost) {

        Log.v("KEYWORD", "KEYWORD GOING UP:"+jsonPost);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpResponse response = null;

        try {
            HttpGetWithEntity request = new HttpGetWithEntity(url);
            Log.v("UPU", "URL:" + url +" token:"+token);

            request.setHeader("X-AUTHORIZATION", token);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonPost);
            request.setEntity(se);

            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;

    }
```

My log to check the json i am posting looks like this:

03-09 14:38:01.034: V/KEYWORD(11739): KEYWORD CREATED: {"keyword":"e"}

The problem is, it seems like the JSON never reaches the api or is ignored.  Does anyone know what i am doing wrong..

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GET method will not send the request.entity to the server..

instead of using "request.setEntity() .."

just access the parms of the request setting " "keyword": "X S"" as parm K-V pair and append them to the url that you are GETTING:

domain/path?keyword=X%20S

do not use the entity unless you are POST or PUT method.

Comment: Oh my god.. i am so burnt out.. you are absolutely right.. all i see is json and thats not what it is expecting.. need sleep.. thanks